# adapterArgs.rawResponse.getHeaders is not a function

Tags: next.js, shopify-api-node

i am trying to connect next13 route.ts with shopify node api with the following

```
export async function GET(request: Request, res:Response) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  const shop = searchParams.get('shop') as string;
  const service = new ShopifyService();
  return service.shopify.auth.begin({
    shop: service.shopify.utils.sanitizeShop(searchParams.get('shop'), true),
    callbackPath: '/auth/callback',
    isOnline: false,
    rawRequest: request,
  });
}
```

where shopifyService is just a simple typescript class

```
export class ShopifyService {
    public shop: string | undefined;
    public accessToken: string | undefined;
    public shopify : any;
    // private shopify;
    constructor() {
         this.shopify = shopifyApi({
             // The next 4 values are typically read from environment variables for added security
             apiKey: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
             apiSecretKey: process.env.CLIENT_ID!,
             scopes: process.env.SCOPES!.split(','),
             hostName: process.env.HOST!,
             apiVersion: ApiVersion.April22,
             isEmbeddedApp: true,
             
         });
      
    }
}
```

when i try to access my app from shopify admin it gives me following error :

```
- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusCode')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/node/adapter.js:25:49)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:177:71)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Module.__awaiter (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:159:12)
    at nodeConvertIncomingResponse (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/node/adapter.js:23:20)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/@shopify/shopify-api/lib/auth/oauth/oauth.js:42:79)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:162:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

any idea what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

you might try using a different adapter, such as
`import '@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/web-api';`

[the web-api adapter sets the headers property](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/823562e8f0c844c4976c5490810f1a8a9ba4ca4d/packages/shopify-api/adapters/web-api/adapter.ts#L17-L20). this works in svelte, but unsure about next..

see also [shopify-api docs](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/tree/823562e8f0c844c4976c5490810f1a8a9ba4ca4d/packages/shopify-api).

Comment: Good shout! that works for me.